# iPython history of valid commands

Tags: python, ipython

I am learning python using IPython. When I did something nice I like to copy this into some kind of private CheatSheet-file. Therefore I use the iPython `%hist` command. I am wondering, if there is a way to only print those commands which had been syntactically correct and did not raise an error. Any ideas?

Comment: short answer: NO ...

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying ipython notebook ? (I've used it on a couple of training courses)

You access the interatctive python via a web browser creating 'boxes' of runnable code. So if you ran a block, it gave the answer you wanted and threw no errors, you could then create another block and move on (preserving the bit you wished to keep). If it threw an error or didn't produce the expected result, you could edit and re-run until it did.

Your boxes of code can be interspersed with html markup notes, graphs, diagrams - you name it.
The whole notebook can then be saved for later access and re-run when re-loaded.